# How to start own Android App with specific protocol/intent and pass parameter?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, cordova

I am trying to find a way for building this behaviour.

For example you call foo://bar
No matter where, if browser or NFC tag.

Accordingly your App should be started with passed param bar.

My approach is phonegap, where I wanted to register an intent in its manifest.xml.

Which are the next steps? 
How do I register the intent?
Where and when do I create the intent and catch my value?

I am not too lazy for looking up and learn, but need your support to get involved into Android development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example you call foo://bar

Don't use `foo://bar`. Use `http://foo/bar`, for some domain `foo` that you own. That way, everybody can use the link, and for people who do not have your app installed, you can display a Web page that takes them to the app in question.

> No matter where, if browser or NFC tag.

You will need to come up with a definitive list someday, as they do not all use the same mechanism.

For a browser link, and probably stuff like Barcode Scanner for QR codes, you would add this `<intent-filter>` to the manifest for your `<activity>`:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="foo" android:scheme="http" />
  </intent-filter>
```

For an NFC tag written to using standard NDEF, you would add this `<intent-filter>` to the manifest for your `<activity>`:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
          <data android:scheme="http" android:host="foo" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: okay then lets focus on nfc. how would the counterpart look like? i mean the implementation in the specific java class. would be my app started now and trigger my default view? or can i trigger a view depending on my throupassed parameter?

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: "would be my app started now and trigger my default view?" -- Android does not have a concept of a "default view", and NFC does not start a "view" in any case. Whichever **activity** you have the `<intent-filter>` on will be started. "or can i trigger a view depending on my throupassed parameter?" -- only if you know all possible "throupassed parameters" up front and can encode `<intent-filter>` elements to match. And then, only if by "trigger a view" you really mean what Android calls "start an activity".

Comment: I know, I guess my description was to weird. My App is starting with <data android:scheme="http" android:host="foo" /> and the URI on my NFC "http://foo/bar". Now I want to pass "bar" as parameter into my app. I found something with android:path. Is this the way to go?

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: "Now I want to pass "bar" as parameter into my app" -- call `getIntent().getData()` in your activity to get the `Uri` that contains `http://foo/bar`, and pick out whatever information you need. "I found something with android:path. Is this the way to go?" -- not if you want to support more than `bar`.